# delphi how to search with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

How can I search a table (and multiple tables) at once where there is a WHERE clause. I know how to search a single table for either all (*) or the fields in the tables. That code is below, I was wondering how I should alter it for searching in multiple tables or with a WHERE clause.

Code I have on searching one table:

```
procedure searchonefield(sqlcommand, fieldwanted:string, list:TStringlist)
var i:integer;
templist:TStringlist;
begin
  ADOQ.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data  Source='+name+';';
  ADOQ.Close;
  ADOQ.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQ.SQL.Add(sqlcommand);
  ADOQ.Open;
  ADOQ.First;
  templist:=TStringlist.create;
  if ADOQ.RecordCount>1 then
    begin
      for I := i to ADOQ.RecordCount do
        begin
          templist.add(ADOQ.FieldByName(field).AsString);
          ADOQ.Next;
        end;
    end
  else
    templist.add(ADOQ.FieldByName(field).AsString);
  list:=templist;
  templist.free;
end;
```

Where my sqlcommand would be something like:

> 'SELECT Username FROM Usertable'

What I want to do is a command like:

> 'SELECT Username FROM Usertable WHERE ID='+id number+'

and

> 'SELECT Usertable.Username, Test.Testscore FROM Usertable, Test WHERE Usertable.ID=Test.ID AND Test.Testscore>10'

I am unsure if the above statements make sense or would work (should I structuring the statement differently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is a command like:
>
> ```
>  'SELECT Username FROM Usertable WHERE ID='+id number+'
> ```

That's the wrong solution, as it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead:

```
var
  QueryStr: string;
begin
  QueryStr := 'SELECT UserName FROM UserTable WHERE ID = :ID';
  ADOQ.SQL.Text := QueryStr;
  ADOQ.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := ID;
  ADOQ.Open;
```

> and
>
> ```
>    'SELECT Usertable.Username, Test.Testscore FROM Usertable, Test 
>     WHERE Usertable.ID=Test.ID AND Test.Testscore>10'
> ```

This would be better written with a JOIN, and again using parameters if necessary.

```
SELECT 
  U.UserName, T.TestScore 
FROM 
  UserTable u INNER JOIN TestTable T on U.ID = T.ID
WHERE 
  T.TestScore > 10
```

It would appear that your next move should be to find a good SQL tutorial or book.

Comment: Thanks! Any books you could suggest?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I haven't had a SQL book for years now. You should be able to find one at Amazon or your favorite book store; Amazon in particular allows reviews and comments, and you can sort by review.